# How can I make an ImageView in my database cursor-backed ListView clickable?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a list of people that I am pulling from the database with a [modified] SimpleCursorAdapter. I then iterate over the cursor and print information out in a ListView in my app.

Right now, it is coded so that when I click on a row, my app performs a function based on information retrieved from the database. However, what I would like to do is make it so that when I click on an ImageView within the row, my app will perform the appropriate function based on information retrieved from the database.

What I want is when I click the "status" ImageView, I want it to perform function "A", and when I click the "location" ImageView, I want it to perform function "B".

Where I am having trouble is isolating the ImageView within the ListView row for using the setOnItemClickListener on just that ImageView instead of the entire row. I'm pretty sure I need to further modify my modified cursor adapter, but I am unsure of how.

Here is what I have:

**Home.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout studentSwipeRefresh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        studentSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.student_swipe_refresh);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        drawTheStudentView();

        studentSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeColors(Color.parseColor(Constants.RED), Color.parseColor(Constants.ORANGE), Color.parseColor(Constants.YELLOW), Color.parseColor(Constants.GREEN), Color.parseColor(Constants.BLUE), Color.parseColor(Constants.INDIGO), Color.parseColor(Constants.VIOLET));
        studentSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                studentSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                drawTheStudentView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawTheStudentView(){
        DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        Cursor studentCursor = myDBHelper.getStudentsCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"_id","studentID","status","location"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.student_number_textview, R.id.student_id_textview};
        // What I want it to be ...
        // int[] toViews = {R.id.student_number_textview, R.id.student_id_textview, R.id.student_status_imageview, R.id.student_location_imageview};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.student_layout, studentCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        // Replace the _id column with a student count
        mySimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                String counter = Integer.toString((cursor.getPosition()+1));
                TextView modifiedTextView = (TextView) view;
                if(columnIndex == 0){
                    modifiedTextView.setText(counter);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.student_row);

        // Listen for somebody clicking on a Student ID, and process
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor subCursor = (Cursor) mySimpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
                String studentIDNumber = subCursor.getString(subCursor.getColumnIndex("studentID"));

                StudentStatus studentStatus = (StudentStatus) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(Constants.TAB_INDEX_PATIENT_VITALS));
                studentStatus.setStudentIDNumber(studentIDNumber);

                myViewPager.setCurrentItem(Constants.TAB_INDEX_PATIENT_VITALS);
            }
        });

        // Draw the list
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Pass me a tab index (see Constants.java) and I'll return a refrence to that tab.
    private String getFragmentTag(int tagID){
        return "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + tagID;
    }
}
```

**AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.WHITE));
        } else {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.LIGHTGREY));
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

**student_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_number_textview"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="@style/StudentStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_id_textview"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        style="@style/StudentStyle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/student_status_button"
        style="@style/studentIconLink"
        android:src="@drawable/status_icon"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/student_location_button"
        style="@style/studentIconLink"
        android:src="@drawable/location_icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would look into RecyclerViews or, if nothing else, ViewHolders for your ListView (not answering your question with this but for efficiency). But what you need to do is set `onClickListener`s to your `view`s that gets inflated in the `getView` portion of your `adapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your adapter to add click listeners:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  // your code goes here, then add the following
     ImageView statusButton = row.findViewById(R.id.student_status_button);
     ImageView locationButton = row.findViewById(R.id. student_location_button);
     OnClickListener statusButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notifyStatusButtonListenerClicked(position);
        }
     };
     OnClickListener locationButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notifyLicationButtonListenerClicked(position);
        }
    };
  return row;
}
```

Both notifications could be delivered to your activity/fragment through Interfaces. Simply add methods like notifyLicationButtonListenerClicked(int position) that would call a method on a listener that implements your interface. Also make sure you remove the existing setOnItemClickListener listener that you set per row.

Answer (score 1):

In your cursor adapter make a static class to hold the elements of list(static is not mandatory) then initialize those elements in getView

use 
    public void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)

method of cursor adapter to set on click listener to any element of list view

example:

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.mImage= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
view.setTag(viewHolder);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
viewHolder.mImage.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  //do stuff
});
}

public static Class ViewHolder{
  public ImageView mImage;
}
```

you can use imageButton (this is just an example)